# Use case condition in stored procedure to update table

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have an existing table in the database. I want to update a column value with 1 or 2 by making a condition on another column value of the same table and I want to do it with a script

Below is the stored procedure script which I wrote but it is not updating the table.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[updateDocumentCategory]
AS
BEGIN
    UPDATE cmdocuments
    SET docCategoryId = CASE 
                           WHEN (docUploadable = 'Y') THEN 2
                           WHEN (docUploadable = 'N') THEN 1
                        END
END
```

**Provided below is the sample data**

[image]

Comment: How do you execute the stored procedure? What other values can be in `docUploadable`?

Comment: Your syntax appears correct... so if its not working maybe your data isn't what you think it is? Sample data and expected results would help. Also, do you really want to update the entire table? You can always use your case expression in your query without hardcoding it to a column.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning
 docUploadable can have two values either 'Y' or 'N'

Comment: @DaleK, Yes I want to update my entire table with condition set in script. I do not understand your question " so if its not working maybe your data isn't what you think it is?"  answer to your question as per understanding the existing data of "docUploadable" is 'Y' or 'N' and my expected results are set docCategoryId to 2 when 'Y' , set  docCategoryId to 1 when 'N'

Comment: @AlwaysLearning, I have executed the script by "Execute" action of SQL Server. It executed successfully. After that i have query table "Select * from cmdocuments" where i found no change in docCategoryId column

Comment: @DaleK, I have updated the question, added the sample data image with it you can see the sample data in question

Comment: Try and avoid images in future - add data as formatted text.

Comment: I suggest you create a [mre] using dbfiddle because I can't reproduce the issue you are having. You update statement looks fine.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217429/discussion-between-noman-and-dale-k).

Comment: "Provided below is the sample data" **That is not the way to provide sample data.** Sample data should be provided as DDL + DML (create table and insert statements) so that we can copy it to a test environment. Please avoid using images for data.

Comment: @ZoharPeled got it

Comment: Are you running this procedure by itself, or is it nested inside another procedure, or being called from an application? Is there an explicit transaction somewhere? Does the table have any triggers on it?

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit long for a column.

Indeed, it is *not* updating the table.  How can I tell?  If it did, then the value would be `NULL`, not `0`.

This suggests that the problem is that the stored procedure is not being called.  If that is the case, you can just update the table using the specified `update` statement.

However, if this is something that you really need to be consistent, I would suggest using a computed column:

```
ALTER TABLE cmdocuments ADD docCategoryId AS (
    CASE WHEN docUploadable = 'Y' THEN 2
         WHEN docUploadable = 'N' THEN 1
    END);
```

This will ensure that `docCategoryId` has the correct value *without having to update the table*.  Then the stored procedure won't even be needed.

Comment: I have executed a simple update commands instead of using stored procedure   `update cmdocuments set docCategoryId = 1 where docUploadable = 'N'`  `update cmdocuments set docCategoryId = 2 where docUploadable = 'Y'`